# Android getting locales related to app language

Tags: android, locale

I have an application which allow user select the group of language.

The languages list i getting with

```
Locale[] localesList = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
```

But this method returns me a list locales related to current device locale.

What i mean?

- Application is on ENGLISH locale now.(All strings gettings from strings.xml file)
- Device on Russian locale.

When i try to get language list it display me all languages on Russian language.

How i can getting locales list related on application locale, not on device locale?

Comment: Do you want get current strings.xml locale?

Comment: @jakubbialkowskiactually no. i want to getting current available locales on ENGLISH writing.